# Set variable to %%f

Tags: batch-file

This is the test code for my program.  The program gets all the files with the file extension .txt opens it then does tasks and then saves the file as a .pdf

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@ECHO OFF
set test = hi
for /R  %%f in (*.txt) do (
  @echo %%f
  echo test =  "%%f"
  set test =  "%%f"
  echo %test%
  set test =!test:~0,-4!
  echo !test!
  )
  pause
)
endlocal

pause
```

Because in the program there is a specific way to export I am sending the file name to the usual save window using SendKeys in a VBS script.  I am trying to remove the file extension but it is not working.  I just get Echo is off because the variable wont set properly

I also tried this

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
set variable = 
for /R %%f in (*.vc6) do (
  @echo %%f 
  FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ("%%f") DO (
    ECHO filedrive=%%~di
       SET filedrive=%%~di

    ECHO filepath=%%~pi
    SET filepath=%%~pi   
    ECHO filename=%%~ni

    set filename=%%~ni 
    ECHO fileextension=%%~xi

    ECHO !fileextension!
    set noext = %%filedrive%%%%filepath%%%%filename%%
    ECHO !noext!

  )
  pause
)
endlocal

pause
```

But I still get the same output of echo is off.  Ideally I could get the second one working because I need to save it in a different folder

Before this is marked as a duplicate because there do seem to be others like this.  I have looked through them and nothing has worked.

Comment: Remove all spaces surrounding `=`  in `set` command. For instance,  `set test =  "%%f"` defines variable `%test %`. Use `set "test=%%f"` instead.

Comment: Worked for the first one going to test the second and things like that are why I am not going into comp sci or things that are coding intensive

Comment: Simply use `set "noext=%%~dpnf"` omitting the inner `%%i` loop at all.